# Mirroring content/photos between devices — Tripple the iCloud backup?

Tags: icloud, backup

I own an iPhone 7+, an iPad, and most recently a new MacBook Pro…  so I'm starting to look at the more intelligent syncing of content between devices.

If I mirror my photos (for example) or other documents between devices through iOS, does that effectively *tripple* the storage used in iCloud to back up that content, or is there a bit of intelligence to avoid backing up synch'd content multiple times?

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't.  iCloud is a syncing solution.  That means it will sync **everything** to **all devices** signed-in with the same Apple ID.

You can read more about setting up iCloud from [this Apple support page](http://www.apple.com/icloud/setup/).

The amount of storage will be same on all your iOS devices.  It might different on macOS because of optimized storage.  It will never be more space (or tripled).

Comment: But iCloud is also also a backup solution for my iOS devices (with a set amount of space I pay for)... so the question is — If the photos (for example) are synced across devices, are they being backed up multiple times or does the iCloud backup have the intelligence to store that data only once?

Comment: It's not really a backup, it's syncing everything you have in iCloud Drive or Photos to all other devices.  You're treating it like a backup but it's really not designed for that.  From [Apple](http://www.apple.com/icloud/): iCloud securely stores your photos, videos, documents, music, apps, and more — and keeps them updated across all your devices."